# OpenCV: Tracing marker lines on video capture. What's the best way?

Tags: opencv, contour, edge-detection

I am looking for ways to capture a marker-drawn empty shape on my camera. 
It is something like drawing a rectangle or a circle or ellipse( 2/3 the size of the card) on a blank postcard, with a marker of any color.
I want to use openCV to "trace over" the exact lines when I switch on my camera. i.e. video capture.

What I have now is

1. cvtColor to gray.
2. bilateral filter(5, 100, 100)
3. Canny (lower: 50, max 255)
4. findContours
5. drawContours, onto my frame.

While this is working for now, I am guessing there might be a better way since what I'm detecting is quite clear.
 A solid color against a white background. Is there a better way to detect and trace over my lines?

P.S. The above fails when my marker is thinner. I hope it works with pencils